# Create and update array value index with key names in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, key

I'm creating array  `arr` with `0` values and variable number `nmb = 2 // 4, 6..` of index's:

```
for (n = 0; n < nmb; n++) {
    arr.push(0);  
}
```

my array:

```
[0, 0]
```

then update with increment value by index `arr[1] = arr[1] + 1;`:

```
[0, 1]
```

and displaying scores by index `console.log("Name:", arr[0], "Case:", arr[1]);`.

I'm trying to figure out, how to create array, add different key names with default zero values by variable number of names. Then update, getting value by index or key name:

```
[Name: 0, Case: 1]
```

Use array according described scenario:

```
 var arr = new Array();
 var keyNames = ["Name", "Case"];
  for (n = 0; n < keyNames.length; n++) {
    arr[keyNames[n]] = 0;
  }
```

but result looks like this:

```
[ NaN, NaN, NaN, Name: 0, Case: 0 ]
```

Comment: It's not very clear to be what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Spectric Hello, sorry just typo with shortcutting example names . I'm trying to create array with key names, and update zero value by index, use value by key name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the values in an object, by key name, then look up the value by key name, and increment the value by key name, derived from looking up the key name in an array by index.

```js
const keyNames = ['Name', 'Case'];
const store = {};

for (const kn of keyNames) {
  store[kn] = 0;
}

const incrementStore = (index) => {
  store[keyNames] += 1;
};

const printStore = () => {
  keyNames.map(kn => `${kn}: ${store[kn]}`).join(', ');
};


incrementStore(1);

printStore();
// Name: 0, Case: 1
```